# Where do I find the text and links used for Transactional emails?

Tags: magento2.4.3, transactional-mail, shipment-email

I've configured our Magento 2 transactional emails, they are sending correctly and content is mostly correct. We use Royal Mail for most shipping and the Magento order shipment is automatically updated with a Royal Mail shipment reference and included in the order shipment email for each despatch.

The default order shipment template includes the shipment reference and also the text label 'Tracking number', this will obviously lead to customer confusion as it isn't specifically a tracking reference. The email tracking link is linked to our website rather than Royal Mail tracking and displays the shipment reference, no tracking details.

My question is; where can I find the text labels and links used in the email template in order to correct them?
I'm assuming this line is calling the information I need to edit:

layout handle="sales_email_order_shipment_track" shipment_id=$shipment_id order_id=$order_id

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can through https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/templates/email/ to know more about transactional email templates and how you can customize them.

**UPDATE**
layout handle `sales_email_order_shipment_track` corresponds to `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_shipment_track.xml`

Comment: Thanks for the useful link, there's some helpful information there. However, it doesn't tell me where I can find the specific text I'm attempting to modify, it's the 'layout handle' which is calling a block or similar which is rendering the text. This is not covered in the Adobe doc.

Comment: @Sparko I have added one more point.

Comment: Thanks Anshu. It appears I'm looking in the wrong place for the text and formatting I need, I'll have to spend a little more time on this problem.